# Left hand must be a variable

Tags: java

If i do this it works

```
elements.getElement(j).getValues().getArray()[i]=(elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)-minimum)/(maximum-minimum);
```

But if I do this it tells me that he left side should be a variable

```
elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)=(elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)-minimum)/(maximum-minimum);
```

The two functions are

```
double[] getArray(){
    return array;
}

double getVariable(int position){
    return array[position];
}
```

I believe that what is in the front does not matter and it is working properly and the mistake must lie somewhere at the end. And how come when I assign let's say like this ( 1st row) it works , which means it is a variable but when I try to assign something to it like(2nd row) it does not work.How dumb am I ? What am I missing ?

```
double max=elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i);
elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)=0.0;
```

Comment: Seems right; you're trying to assign to the result of a function. You should be doing something like `setVariable` that takes the position and sets `array[position]` to the value you pass in. Java has a very regular, if verbose, syntax, and you cannot make up new syntax.

Comment: Baseline: wiht `getVariable()` you return a primitive and primitives are returned as literals (not as variables). For the exact same reason `int i = 1++;` won't work, since `1` is a literal.

Comment: But how come the first one works ? It seems a little bit odd that one variant works and another one does not since they basically do the same thing. Any ideas ?

Comment: @myheadhurts because arrays behave like objects. The method returns a reference to an array.

Comment: Basically, it wasn't bad thinking at all. There are other programming languages where you could write a function that would let you return a location ("l-value"), and it makes sense in certain situations. Only: Java just wasn't designed that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
getVariable(i)
```

Is definitely different from

```
getArray()[i]
```

The first one returns an array, which may be indexed by `[]` and then used as a valid l-value.
The latter returns a value (r-value), that can only be used on the left side of an assignemnt.

In simple words, you can not assign a value to a value, but you can assign a value to a memory location specified by an array and an index.

```
0 = 5 // this just won't work
array[0] = 5 // this will, because array[0] is a valid l-value
```

You may, however, create a method that would serve as a setter.

```
void setVariable(int position, double value) {
    array[position] = value;
}
```

It would be used like this

```
elements.getElement(j).getValues().setVariable(i, value);
```

Comment: ah , the 0=5 finally made me understand. yeah pretty basic error but just couldn't wrap my head around it. Thank you all for the responses :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory: you cannot assign to a result returned from a method call.

It may appear that your first code snippet makes an assignment to the result returned from a method, but that appearance is misleading: your first code snippet applies the index operator `[]` to the array result of calling a method, and only then assigns to the result produced by the `[]` operator.

Assigning to what's returned by `[]` is allowed, hence your first code snippet compiles and runs correctly. The second snippet, however, applies `[]` inside method implementation, and returns a `double`. At this point the returned `double` has no connection to the array from which it came, making it illegal to assign.

In order to fix this, add another method, and perform the assignment inside:

```
void setVariable(int position, double newValue){
    array[position] = newValue;
}
...
elements.getElement(j)
    .getValues()
    .setVariable(i
    , (elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)-minimum)/(maximum-minimum)
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you access an array with the bracket characters, `[i]`, that is an array access expression, and Java allows that expression on the left side of an assignment operator.

However, with the call to `getVariable(i)`, that is a method, and the things returned by methods are always values, which are not allowed on the left side of an assignment operator.  Where would the value to be assigned go?  We only have a value, not a variable.

If you want to avoid exposing the array, you can create and use a `setVariable` method to write a value in a list at a specified index.

```
void setVariable(int position, double value){
    array[position] = value;
}


elements.getElement(j).getValues().setVariable(i, 
    elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)-minimum)/(maximum-minimum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not substitutions, so when you are doing

```
elements.getElement(j).getValues().getVariable(i)
```

you think that this is equivalent to this

```
elements.getElement(j).getValues().getArray()[i]
```

but it is not. Why? It is quite simple;

Return value of first call will be a `VALUE` of `array[i]`.
In the second case, return of the function is `array` itself, so you can assign elements to it and read from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `getVariable()` function returns a `value`. You can use it any place you can use a `primitive`. So instead of this:

```
int x = 7;
```

You can do this:

```
int x = getVariable(i);
```

However, note that you could **not** do this:

```
3 = 7;
```

Since 3 is a `value`, not a `variable`. Your code is trying to do something like that, so you're getting an error.

The `getArray()` function works because it returns an array, and you then use the `[]` index operator on it, which you **can** use as a variable.

```
getArray()[i] = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think about it like this.

Functions have this form `countLetters("hello")` and they visually send their return value to the left;

```
int count = countLetters("hello");
      <---------------------+
```

What you’re doing is visually bumping on the parenthesis.

```
getValue(1) = 5;
  <------+X<--+
```

Hope this helps you remember.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there these methods

```
public int[] getArray(){
    return array;
}

public int getValue(int i){
   return array[i];
}
```

Your question implies you expect these both to work

```
getArray()[0] = 2;
getValue(0) = 3;
```

The first one works because if you "unwind" the call, you get

```
int[] arrayFromMethod = getArray();
arrayFromMethod[0] = 2;
```

The second one won't work because you are getting an `int` value, not an array.  And attempting to unwind it is really the equivalent of

```
// pretend array[0] is already 42
 42 = 3;  // Nope
```

It isn't the same as

```
int x = array[0];
x = 3;
```

because you inline the call when you say `getValue(i) = 3`, which isn't allocating a new variable.  And even if it did, the value would be gone as soon as the next statement is reached, so it doesn't have any use.